# Flask - Gevent - Pushbullet - Twilio - This operation would block forever

Tags: python, flask, twilio, pushbullet

so I have the following app that I'm working on https://github.com/SimplySynced/simplyfishy/tree/master 
and i'm running into this error when I trigger my float switch and try to send a message via twilio and pushbullet.

```
File "/home/pi/simplyfishy/simplyfishyenv/local/lib/python3.5/site-    packages/gevent/hub.py", line 630, in switch
    return RawGreenlet.switch(self)
gevent.hub.LoopExit: ('This operation would block forever', <Hub at 0x7451b210 epoll pending=0 ref=0 fileno=17>)
```

Full Traceback https://pastebin.com/E0FJm8ZW.  I've tried using gevent.spawn when I call the functions as well and this still provided the same issue.  I have made sure that my monkey patch line is at the top of the files.  Now this error will only occur on the first trigger, if I continue to trigger the float switch both message go through with no issues.  No errors at all going forward.